# how to pass parameter in (translation) string

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to pass param values to translation

item.title is `Healthy` and
heading is `Patient Info`

translation file has translation under `project/healthy_patient_info`
This is what i have so far

```
      {item.title.toLowerCase()}
      {heading.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase()}
```

tried this to see what it returns but getting error `project is not function`

```
      {t('project/'`${item.title.toLowerCase()}``${heading.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase()}`)}
```

how can i add these in the code below so i can access translation?

```
let text = null;
  if (isItemDefined(item)) {
      text = (
        <div className="well-Text--dark well-Font--body">
          {t("project/item.title_heading"}
        </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: without knowing more about the translation library you're using, it's hard to say, but it definitely looks like you're misusing the template literals. try something like `\`project/${item.title.toLowerCase()}.${heading.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase()}\`` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it. the real issue was item is undfined when the page loads hence it wasnt working

```
  let itemTitle = null;
  let itemHeading = null;
  if (isItemDefined(item)) {
    itemTitle = item.title.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase();
    itemHeading = heading.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase();
  }
```

and adding following for translation

```
    {t(`project/${itemTitle}_${itemHeading}`)}
```